# Existence of subspace which is totally non-invariant under unitary transformation

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

Given a complex Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ of dimension $d$ - interpreted as vectorspace over $\mathbb{R}$ with dimension $2d$. And the space $L(\mathcal{H},\mathbb{C}^4)$ of all linear operators from $\mathcal{H}$ to $\mathbb{C}^4$ also interpreted as vectorspace over $\mathbb{R}$. Does there exists any subspace $E \subset L(\mathcal{H},\mathbb{C}^4)$ such that for any $B\in E$ and all $U \in U(\mathbb{C}^4)\setminus \{\pm I\}$  : $UB \notin E$?

In other words I'm looking for a real-subspace $E$ of dimension $\dim_\mathbb{R}(E) = 8d-16$ such that the map

$$R: E\subset L(\mathcal{H},\mathbb{C}^4) \to L(\mathcal{H})$$
$$ B \mapsto B^*B$$

is injective.

Comment: But if we look at some unitary transformation $U$ then $R(UB) = B^*U^*UB = B^*B$, so the map is not injective on the whole space $L(\mathcal{H},\mathbb{C}^4)$.

Comment: My apologies, you are right!